# Dynamic HTML5 Canvas Animation

Tags: html, animation, dynamic, canvas

I want to create a dynamic HTML5 canvas animation. This animation should use server side variables.

The goal is to show a canvas in the browser with a path and a number of objects (a server side variable) which are moving this path. Each object should have speed (server side variable). So every object is moving with a different speed. An object represents a user and every user can change the speed of his object and this change should update every running canvas, so every user watches the same animation.

Is this possible to create with HTML5 Canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the canvas can be part of the solution as it's very convenient for fast animations client-side.

But you'll have more work server side, and in between.

Server side, you should use a technology enabling easy multitasking and long tasks. Java or Go servers can do that easily (for example).

For the sending of thobject properties (including position and speed) from the server to the browser, I'd recommend websockets as they enable the server to push the data as soon as they're computed to the browsers (the browser still has to open the connection but it can keep it open as long as it wants).